# Знаки препинания при конструкциях с союзом "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Ответьте к какому шагу алгоритма соответствуют знаки препинания при конструкциях с союзом как: 1-наличие сочетаний; 2а-фразеологизм; 2б-слова перед КАК;
2в-состав сказуемого; 2г-значение тождества или "в качестве"; 2д-обособление.
1 Глаза за блестящими очками как будто ничего не видящие и беспокойные (И.А.Бунин). 2. никакой адрес календарь и справочное место не доставят такого верного известия, как Невский проспект (Гоголь).3. В самых лучших, дружеских и простых отношениях лесть и похвала необходимы, как подмазка для колес, чтобы они ехали. (Толстой). 4. Нравственность, оторванная от жизни, так же безнравственна, как жизнь, утратившая всякое нравственное содержание( Плеханов) 5. Только единственный сын Анны Павловны, Александр Федорович, спал, как следует спать двенадцатилетнему юноше, богатырским сном; а в доме все суетились и хлопотали (Достоевский).6 Между тем ночь приближалась и росла как грозовая туча (Тургенев) 7. Принявший мир как звонкий дар как злата горсть я стал богат. (Блок)

Comment: Ваши полдюжины вопросов сведите к одному, иначе последует указание на дверь.

Comment: Указание на дверь может и последует, но, разумеется, не потому, что так кому-то хочется. Задавать хоть сто вопросов не запрещено, но это сильно смахивает на  домашнее задание. Здесь их не делают. Вы начните, покажите, что не ясно. И, кстати, что такое алгоритм?

Comment: Вот именно что это все разные вопросы тут у каждого один ответ а домашнее задание на несколько листов все с этой темы, если не знаете что такое алгоритм прочитайте вопрос внимательнее

Answer (score 1):

1. Глаза за блестящими очками как будто ничего не видящие и беспокойные. Конструкция со словом «как» входит в состав сказуемого «как будто ничего не видящие и беспокойные».
2. Никакой адрес календарь и справочное место не доставят такого верного известия, как Невский проспект. «Как» присоединяет неполное сравнительное придаточное предложение: как [доставит] Невский проспект.
3. В самых лучших, дружеских и простых отношениях лесть и похвала необходимы, как подмазка для колес, чтобы они ехали. «Как» присоединяет неполное сравнительное придаточное предложение: как [необходима] подмазка для колес, чтобы они ехали.
4. Нравственность, оторванная от жизни, так же безнравственна, как жизнь, утратившая всякое нравственное содержание. «Как» присоединяет обстоятельство «как жизнь, утратившая всякое нравственное содержание» - сравнительный оборот.
5. Только единственный сын Анны Павловны, Александр Федорович, спал, как следует спать двенадцатилетнему юноше, богатырским сном; а в доме все суетились и хлопотали. «Как» присоединяет вставную конструкцию - как следует спать двенадцатилетнему юноше.
6. Между тем ночь приближалась и росла как грозовая туча. Слова «как грозовая туча» тесно связаны со сказуемым (или входит в состав сказуемого?), имеет значение обстоятельства.
7. Принявший мир как звонкий дар как злата горсть я стал богат. Конструкция  «звонкий дар как злата горсть» - приложение, «как» имеет значение *в качестве*.

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в виду этот алгоритм:

**1.Есть сочетания типа «так… как и», «такой… как и», «столь… как и», «не кто иной, как», «никто иной, как» или нет (если есть, ставьте запятые с одной стороны в начале и в конце предложения, с обеих – в середине).**

2.**Есть ПРИЗНАКИ необособления или нет:
(если перед КАК стоит отрицание НЕ либо слова ПРЯМО, ПРОСТО, СОВЕРШЕННО, ИМЕННО, ПОЧТИ, СОВСЕМ, ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ; или это ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЗМ; или СОСТАВ СКАЗУЕМОГО; или значение тождества, характеристики с какой - либо стороны (В КАЧЕСТВЕ)- не обособляйте; если нет - ставьте запятые с одной стороны в начале и в конце предложения, с обеих – в середине).**

Тогда мне видится так:

**1-наличие сочетаний такого...как, так же...как**

*2. никакой адрес календарь и справочное место не доставят такого верного известия, как Невский проспект (Гоголь). 
4. Нравственность, оторванная от жизни, так же безнравственна, как жизнь, утратившая всякое нравственное содержание( Плеханов)*;

**2а-фразеологизм**

*6 Между тем ночь приближалась и росла как грозовая туча (Тургенев);*

**2б-слова перед КАК;** слов не вижу, частицы Не тоже

**2в-состав сказуемого**
*1 Глаза за блестящими очками как будто ничего не видящие и беспокойные (И.А.Бунин).*;

**2г-значение тождества или "в качестве"**

*7. Принявший мир как звонкий дар как злата горсть я стал богат. (Блок);*

**2д-обособление**

*3. В самых лучших, дружеских и простых отношениях лесть и похвала необходимы, как подмазка для колес, чтобы они ехали. (Толстой). 
5. Только единственный сын Анны Павловны, Александр Федорович, спал, как следует спать двенадцатилетнему юноше, богатырским сном; а в доме все суетились и хлопотали (Достоевский).*